# GAE Objectify load object created in transaction within same transaction

Tags: java, google-app-engine, transactions, objectify

I try to use objectify transaction, but I have some issues when I need to reload an object created in the same transaction.

Take this sample code

```
@Entity
public class MyObject
{
    @Parent
    Key<ParentClass> parent;

    @Index
    String foo;
}


ofy().transact(new VoidWork()
{
    @Override
    public void vrun()
    {
        ParentClass parent = load();// load the parent
        String fooValue = "bar";

        Key<ParentClass> parentKey = Key.create(ParentClass.class, parent.getId())
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject(parentKey);
        myObject.setFoo(fooValue);

        ofy().save().entity(myObject).now();

        MyObject reloaded = ofy().load().type(MyObject.class).ancestor(parentKey).filter("foo", fooValue).first().now();

        if(reloaded == null)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("error");
        }
    }
});
```

My object reloaded is always null, maybe I miss something, but logically within a transaction I can query an object which was created in the same transaction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Datastore differs from relational databases in this particular case. The documentation states that -

> Unlike with most databases, queries and gets inside a Cloud Datastore
>   transaction do not see the results of previous writes inside that
>   transaction. Specifically, if an entity is modified or deleted within
>   a transaction, a query or lookup returns the original version of the
>   entity as of the beginning of the transaction, or nothing if the
>   entity did not exist then.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#isolation_and_consistency

Comment: Thanks for answering, I hope that objectify handle that with local cache within transaction context, but obviously objectify doesn't do this..

Comment: If you did a get-by-key in the transaction, Objectify will give you the object you saved (from the session cache). However, queries are submitted to the datastore's query processor (there's no way to satisfy a query from the session cache) and thus you see the null result set.

Comment: This goes back to "think of the datastore as a key-value store with some additional indexing behavior bolted on". There are some quirks to the query behavior.